# How to find the length of an char array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I want to find the length of this :

```
char *s[]={"s","a","b"};
```

it should count 4 with the /0 but the strlen or sizeof(s)/sizeof(char) gives me wrong answers..
How can i find it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are making an array of `char*` and not of `char`. That's why `strlen` won't work. Use

```
sizeof(s) / sizeof(char*) //should give 3
```

If you want a single string use

```
char s[] = "sab";
```

Answer (score 8):

`sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0])` works no matter what type `s` contains.

Comment: +1: I like `sizeof s / sizeof *s` instead (or, using redundant parenthesis, `sizeof (s) / sizeof (*s)`).

Answer (score 3):

What you have defined is not a string hence there is no NULL terminating character. Here you have declared pointers to 3 separate strings. BTW, you should declare your array as `const char*`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to determine the length of an array in C. Arrays in C are represented by a continuous block in a memory.

You must keep the length of the array as a separate value.

Answer (score 1):

strlen works if you terminate your array with null character. You cannot find number of elements in a char array unless you keep track of it. i.e store it in some variable like n. Every time you add member increment n and every time you remove decrement n

Answer (score 0):

Why should it count 4? you have 3 pointers to char in this array, it should count 12 on most 32-bit platforms.