# Calculating length of uninitialized char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, sizeof

I want to calculate the length of an (at first) uninitialized char array.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *string_t;
    int loc = sizeof(string_t)/sizeof(*string_t);
    printf("%d", loc);

}
```

I expect `loc` to be `0` but instead `loc` is 8. Can someone tell me why this is and how I can "fix" this to be the answer I expect?

Comment: could you explain why you expected `0` exactly?

Comment: @M.M I've seen on a couple forums (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001661/how-to-find-the-length-of-an-char-array-in-c) that `sizeof(string_t)/sizeof(*string_t)` is how you find the length of a char array

Comment: You don't have any char arrays in your code. Arrays are indicated by `[ ]` .

Comment: @M.M oh, I was thinking that since arrays decay into pointers, I basically have an array

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` is a compile time operator (with the exception of VLA). The value of `sizeof(string_t)/sizeof(*string_t)` is equivalent to `sizeof(char *) / sizeof(char)`, which is the size of a pointer, usually `8` on 64-bit machines.

For uninitialized `char *` pointer, there is no *correct* size, you have to initialize it:

```
char *string_t = "";
```

and use `strlen(string_t)` to get `0`. However, since it's a pointer to a string literal, it's somehow pointless though.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, however for a next step I want to add some characters to `string_t` and then check the size again, `strlen` causes a pointer error for me

Comment: That's why I said it's somehow pointless. You need an actual array `char string_t[1024] = ""`, or use dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 2):

`char *string_t` is a pointer, not an uninitialized `char` array. Its size is fixed to whatever is the size of a pointer on your system, which appears to be eight.

`sizeof(*string_t)` is the same as `sizeof(char)`, so it is fixed at `1` by the C standard. There is no way to produce the behavior that you expect without changing from pointers to arrays.

If you would like to make an array that you resize by `realloc`-ing, you need to make a `struct` that keeps track of both the pointer and the size (or has two pointers pointing to the beginning and to the end of the allocated block).

```
struct dynamic_char_array {
    char *array;
    size_t size;
};

void add_char(struct dynamic_char_array* a, char c) {
    char *tmp = realloc(a->array, (a->size)+1);
    if (tmp) {
        a->array = tmp;
    } else {
        // Do something about a failed allocation
        ...
        return;
    }
    a->array[size++] = c;
}
```

**Note:** You could also use variable-length arrays, but once their size is set, it cannot be changed.

Comment: You write out of bounds if the allocation fails

Answer (score 2):

you don't have a char array, you have a char *. To get what you want you need to something like :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100];
    string[0]=0;
    int loc = strlen(string);
    printf("%d", loc);

}
```

Comment: what if I'm not sure how much space I need?

Comment: then you need to malloc and realloc.  when you get memory of malloc then you do need a pointer so you can point at the memory it gives you.  If you run out, realloc your memory to be bigger

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the length of an uninitialized char array, you have to declare one first. In your code, you wrote `char *string_t;`. This statement declares a pointer to char, rather than an array of char.

An uninitialized char array should be declared using something like `char s[1024];`. To create an initialized one, use `char s[1024] = "foo";`, or `char s[1024] = {'f', 'o', 'o'};`.

So, actually, you are trying to calculate the length of an **undeclared** array, which is obviously impossible.

Answer (score -1):

'char *' is just pointer to char, not char array.
so you can't count array.

use like this

```
char array[100];
int len = sizeof(array);
```